# C++ int literals not in the memory segment for constants?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

From what I know, during program startup, C++ programs initialize a memory segment for constant values.

For example if you do a `cout << "Hello World!";` then the `const char*` argument that `operator<<` receives will point to that memory segment, where the string `"Hello World!"` is.

I was under the impression that all hardcoded literals in the code end up residing in that memory segment during runtime. However I have seen a course where the following pitfall was illustrated:

```cpp
class Data
{
public:
    const int& y;
    Data() : y(123) {}
    void f() 
    {
        int a[10000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            a[i] = 50;
    }
};

void main()
{
    Data d;
    cout << d.y << endl;
    d.f();
    cout << d.y << endl;
}
```

The pitfall was described as the situation that during the execution of the constructor for `Data`, instead of `d.y` ending up pointing to that memory segment dedicated to constant values, a behaviour similar to `int temp = 123; this->y = &temp;` is what actually happens, and since `temp` is on the stack, it will be gone in a second, and after `temp` is gone, `f()` may end up allocating `a` such that the address that `y` points to ends up included in `a` and thus may be overwritten when calling `f()`.

I would like some clarifications on:

1. Is really what happens/can happen?
2. If the answer to 1. is "yes" then why does this happen? Is there some UB somewhere or something like that?
3. If the answer to 1. is "yes" then why was this not fixed? And by fixed I mean a solution similar to what I described above where all literals reside in their own special memory segment?
4. Is there anything else I should know to understand this situation better? (maybe I am not asking the right questions?)

Comment: you can see it in action here:https://godbolt.org/z/hrhd55dMn

Comment: I don't think you are asking the right questions. Your program specifies the *intention*. The compiler compiles that intention to for the program. How it does that is entirely up to it. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if. Because the behaviour of your program is undefined (due to the dangling reference), a compiler is allowed to optimise to `int main(){}`. Once you've fixed that, a good compiler will optimise out `f()`.

Comment: This is UB. Clang detects the issue and reports an error: https://godbolt.org/z/G6b3YPM6s Sadly address sanitizer is happy. Note that changes in optimization flags changes the outcome.

Comment: Note that in professional code "Magic Numbers" are consider as bad, so constant would be introduced, what solves this issue.

Comment: This is correct. `123` is an integer. `"string literal"` is not. String literals have a special rule in this regard.

Comment: @MarekR: Unless you use `const int magic=123;` in a **header** and take a reference to it like this, in which case the ODR sends you right back where you started.

Comment: @DavisHerring why location in header should change anything? Headers exist only in preprocessing stage, constants are generated at compile time. To avoid problems with linking compilers are implicitly add `static` keyword to it.

Comment: @MarekR: Headers are (typically) included more than once, producing an ODR violation from the very implicit `static` you mention if any other multiply defined entity refers to “the” variable that is really one per translation unit.  In C++17, you fix this by marking the variable `inline`.